# Overlapping profile picture in the middle

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Currently i have the following Header(Template from Bootstrap for Responsive Purposes):-

[image: current Header]

But it's not very nice to have a such big navigation pane, so now i want to place the Profile Picture in the middle of the Border like this(The circle should be the profile picture):-

[image: Wanted Header]

The question is, how can I achieve this without using a absolute position which would ruin my responsive design? (It should be a proportion of 50/50)

Edit: The HTML Code for the Profile Picture is:-

```html
<div id="nav_profile">
    <div class="profile_picture">
        <img src="assets/img/profilepicture.png" alt="Profile Picture">
        <figcaption><i class="ion-android-add"></i></figcaption>
        <a id="profile_hover_txt" href="profile.php">View Profile</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS Part is just for the transitions and the styling for the Picture.

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try The Following Code....

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand brand" href="#">Custom Logo</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li> <img width="50px" height="50px" class="img-circle" src="http://i.imgur.com/bQ6Rroe.jpg" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Oh thank you, it fits perfectly even in the mobile view

Comment: Thanks a lot @CentrixDE

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the height of the picture to `200%`. The `float: right;` and `width: 100px;` are just in my code so it works without an image but the principal works without them.

```css
#menu {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: #000000;
}

#pic {
float: right;
width: 100px;
height: 200%;
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<div id="pic"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, now i just have to find a way to get a nice position on the mobile view but i think its not a big problem ;)